# How move to toolbar of browser [selenium] [python]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please tell me how I can move the cursor to the toolbar of browser to see a popup modal window (https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/exit_intent)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class TestExitIntent:

    def setup_method(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/exit_intent')
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    def test_exit_intent(self):
        action = ActionChains(self.driver)
        action.move_by_offset(150, 0)
        action.perform()

        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal-footer']/p").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this [**can not**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295175/use-selenium-and-python-to-move-mouse-outside-of-web-page-area) be done with Selenium / ActionChains.
There are multiple [existing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/49266/how-to-move-mouse-pointer-outside-of-the-actual-web-page) questions about this saying this is not possible.
In Java we can do that with external framework called Robot imported from `java.awt.*`
With Python this probably can be done with [PyAutoIt](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/) but I'm not sure about this.

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(150, 150)
```

Comment: it works, thank you @Prophet

`import pyautogui`

`pyautogui.moveTo(150, 150)`

Comment: Great! Please let me know if the edited answer is what worked for you

Comment: **BUT** There is one feature that affects the performance of this code. 

- If cursor was already in workspace at the beginning of test, then test is passed. 
- If cursor was not directly in workspace after the start of test, then **test failed**.

Comment: What do you mean by workspace? The visible browser screen area?

Comment: Yes, I mean the visible browser screen area

Comment: Maybe you can use ActionChains to set the cursor somewhere on the middle of the screen when test starts and then to perform the move with PyAutoIt?

Comment: I tried to move to the element (title) before PyAutogui, but it doesn't give a positive result anyway

Comment: No, I wrote you to move to the middle of the visible screen, not to the title

Comment: I used `action.move_by_offset(550, 550)` and `action.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to_location(550,550)` - it still fail

Comment: That's strange. Need to see all your code in order to debug it.

Comment: check please @Prophet

Answer (score 0):

- If cursor was not directly in workspace after the start of test, then test failed.
  @prophet

```
class TestExitIntent:

    def setup_method(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\WORK\PycharmProjects\what_can_I_do\chromedriver')
        self.driver.get('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/exit_intent')
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    def test_exit_intent(self):

        action = ActionChains(self.driver)
        #action.move_by_offset(550, 550)
        action.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to_location(550,550)
        action.perform()

        pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100)

        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal-footer']/p").click()
```

Comment: I see. And what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: modal window not opening

Comment: Well, that not seems to be because of ActionChains. Where and how you calling here the `setup_method` and `test_exit_intent`?

Comment: I call "Run test" in IDE pyCharm..

Comment: OK, This is not visible here. Anyway. Try adding a sleep after moving cursor with ActionChains before applying the AutoIt

Comment: `time.sleep(5)` before `pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100)`- it still not open. Maybe it is a bug?

Comment: I don't know, I'm sorry. Try asking a new, separate question about this.